# Click Next Button from Chrome Console Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to click on button from Chrome console

```
<a class="toolTip ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" href="#" role="button" aria-label="next page" data-hasqtip="211" oldtitle="next page" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-211">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text"></span></a>
```

[image]

i have tried

```
document.querySelector("#results > div.results_navigation.top_results_navigation.displayButtons > div.results_pager.ui-widget-content > div.arrow_container > a:nth-child(4)").Click();
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Js functions are case sensitive and you are using **Click** instead of **click**.
Also your html and js code not match. So...

```js
//check if btn was clicked
document.querySelector(".next_page").onclick = function() {
  // indicate that btn was clicked
  this.innerText = 'clicked';
  // set back the text after half a second
  setTimeout(() => document.querySelector(".next_page").innerText = 'button', 500);
};

// click the button every second
setInterval(() => document.querySelector(".next_page").click(), 1000);
```

```html
<a class="next_page" href="#" role="button" aria-label="next page" data-hasqtip="211" oldtitle="next page" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-211">
  <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
  <span class="ui-button-text">button</span></a>
```

Comment: I have Try above Code But its not work in Hare is website link

Comment: https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/#

Answer (score 0):

If the click handlers are added by jQuery, often the native click() method on the HTMLElement will not trigger the jQuery handlers. You can use jQuery to trigger the click and it should trigger the handlers bound with jQuery.

```
$('#results > div.top_results_navigation > div.results_pager a[aria-label="next page"]').trigger('click'); // or .click() even
```

Comment: Its working Fine can You tell me how you make this link i am very new i want to learn web automation from Chrome Console Kindly tell me what video i need to search to Find This kind of video